Importing localhost:8080/js/app.js to regular html file outside root folder of app
I am trying to import my vue.js framework scripts to my regular html file outside the vue.js project folder which is in D:\practice_coding\vuejs\vue-project and my regular html file is in C:\Users\Default\Downloads
running my vue.js framework on localhost:8080 then tried this on my regular html file
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="app"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8080/js/chunk-vendors.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8080/js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

I will be using this in my golang template so that when I create my golang api I dont have to deal with cors error
